# Writing to and reading a array inside another list Python

Tags: python, list, pygame

I want to define 25 different "rectangles" each with 6 different attributes. I first created a list of just 25 five different elements. Then using a different loop I attempted to append the 6 attributes of each rectangle to a list inside the list containing 1-25. This is the error I am getting and I have a feeling that it is due to the fact that I am not assigning what element "list" to assign the new 6 elements to.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tryingRectangle.py", line 37, in <module>
    rectanglePos.append(x, y, width, height)
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (4 given)


# Create the empty array to house the rectangle
rectanglePos = []
rectangleInPos = [rectanglePos]

# Loop 25 times and add rectangle in random x,y position
for i in range(25):
    rectanglePos[i] = i
    height = random.randint(20,400)
    x = i*20
    y = 200
    width = 15
   rectangleInPos.append(rectanglepos[i])

# Ignore me clock = pygame.tme.Clock()

# Loop until user closes
done = False
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
    # Set the background WHITE
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # Process each rectangle
    for i in range(len(rectangle)):
        # Draw the Rectangle
        pygame.draw.rect(SIZE, RED , rectanglePos[i[1]], rectanglePos[i[2]], rectanglePos[i[3]], rectangle[i[4]], 0)
```

I understand I am probably going about this all wrong, but I am confused on how to create a list of list.

Comment: And please add some comments then I can see your problem is done or some problems appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all, we drawing rectangle with this way;

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen(defined before), color(defined before), (coordinate-x,coordinate-y,size on x coord,size on y coord))
```

So actually you **cant** change your *screen* attiribute, because its your pygame screen that you defined size of it.

> This is what you want excatly;

```
import pygame
import random
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600)) #screen

def draw():
    x=random.randint(20,400) #x coordinate
    y=random.randint(20,400) #y coordinate
    x1=random.randint(5,50) #size of rect on x coord
    y1=random.randint(2,30) #size of rect on y coord
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (x,y,x1,y1))
    pygame.display.update() #I wrote it in function so you dont have to write it again and again in main game loop
for i in range(5):
    draw() #call function
```

Output:

[image]

> So I define rect coords and size randomly in a function, and call that function whatever times you want.
>
> With random color by given list of colors:

```
import pygame
import random
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

def draw():
    colorlist=[(255,0,0),(255,255,255)]
    color=random.choice(colorlist)
    x=random.randint(10,590)
    y=random.randint(10,590)
    x1=random.randint(5,50)
    y1=random.randint(2,30)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, (x,y,x1,y1)) #<--- color parameter 
    pygame.display.update()
for i in range(25):
    draw()
```

Output:

[image]

**Or if you want more colors** Just change this one;

```
color1=random.randint(0,255)
color2=random.randint(0,255)
color3=random.randint(0,255)
color=(color1,color2,color3)
```

Output:

[image]

**Here the whole code:**

```
import pygame
import random

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

def draw():
    color1=random.randint(0,255)
    color2=random.randint(0,255)
    color3=random.randint(0,255)
    color=(color1,color2,color3)
    x=random.randint(10,590)
    y=random.randint(10,590)
    x1=random.randint(10,100)
    y1=random.randint(2,30)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, (x,y,x1,y1))
    pygame.display.update()
done=False
while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True

    for i in range(25):
        draw()
        if i==24:
            done=True
```

Try to do this without *if i==24* statement! :-)

> **Edit** for can save the attiributes;

```
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
thebiglist=[] #the list that will save attiributes
def draw():
    color1=random.randint(0,255)
    color2=random.randint(0,255)
    color3=random.randint(0,255)
    color=(color1,color2,color3)
    x=random.randint(10,590)
    y=random.randint(10,590)
    x1=random.randint(10,100)
    y1=random.randint(2,30)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, (x,y,x1,y1))
    thebiglist.append((x,y,x1,y1)) #appending them in a tuple
    pygame.display.update()
done=False
while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True

    for i in range(25):
        draw()
        if i==24:
            done=True
print (thebiglist)
```

Output:

> > > > [(547, 135, 63, 16), (48, 325, 19, 6), (541, 353, 77, 7), (488, 481, 18, 4), (516, 214, 82, 2), (11, 198, 94, 16), (132, 324, 76, 21), (196, 484, 81, 4), (257, 489, 14, 12), (412, 19, 99, 26), (258, 156, 82, 23), (488, 452, 31, 3), (27, 190, 75, 28), (345, 257, 24, 30), (138, 555, 49, 8), (317, 33, 89, 11), (589, 374, 60, 8), (459, 293, 96, 4), (449, 401, 48, 11), (58, 373, 45, 14), (273, 590, 71, 27), (400, 483, 23, 30), (426, 574, 65, 4), (67, 165, 51, 24), (428, 389, 69, 9)]

Comment: I understand doing the drawing this way but later on I want to save the attributes of each rectangle because I want to change the x values for each rectangle. (I am trying to graphically represent multiple different sorting algorithms so recording the position for each rectangle is needed.)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see here, python is using the values at rectanglepos[i] for the parameters of the method append rather than passing it as an actual list. My one thought is to try

```
rectangleInPos.append(list(rectanglepos[i]))
```

But I don't really see how it would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the list of lists is you want a list of triangles with each triangle being composed of a list of attributes? Assuming that is what you want, try this.

```
rectangleInPos = [rectanglePos]

# Loop 25 times and add rectangle in random x,y position
for i in range(25):
    RectanglePos = []
    rectanglePos.append(i)
    rectanglePos.append(height = random.randint(20,400)
    rectanglePos.append(x = i*20)
    rectanglePos.append( y = 200)
    rectanglePos.append(width = 15)
    rectangleInPos.append(rectanglepos)
```